# Why parameter gets assigned to callback?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a javascript function as:

```
function triggerUpload(success, error, callback) {
    var options = {
        type: 'post',
        success: success,
        error: error
    };

    $("input[name=file]").change(function() {
        $(this).parent().ajaxSubmit(options);
    });
    if (callback) {
        callback();
    }
}
```

And i use it as:

```
triggerUpload(function() {
   applyPostAjax(postUrl);
});
```

It works well as: When someone clicks on a `<a href='#' class="upload"> Upload</a>` the `triggerUpload` event occurs with `applyPostAjax` as its parameter assigned to `callback` which can be kept `null` as its optional.

Note: These methods were coded by someone else and i can't get them clearly. I'm a newbie to javascript.

My issues is: i pass only one argument to this function. one would think that argument would get assigned to `success`. How/why does it get assigned to callback? What are these `success`, `error` parameters are here for?

Please explain

Comment: All 3 parameters must be functions, are you passing functions?

Comment: @elclanrs No i just pass one parameter as applyPostAjax(postUrl); and it anyhow gets assigned to callback.

Comment: Not possible, if that's the exact code and you pass one parameter (a function) it will get assigned to `success`. `postUrl` must be a function, is it?

Comment: @elclanrs `postUrl` is not a function it's a url string like 'user/post/20'

Comment: You **need** a function, `success` expects a function. What do you expect to happen with such string?

Comment: It will be assigned to success, and success might be called when $(this).parent().ajaxSubmit(options); is executed successfully. Did you try adding a log statement inside if(callback) and check whether it is actually assigning to callback or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters `success` and `error` are callback functions (same like the parameter you decided to call "callback") that gets executed when the `ajaxSubmit` method either successfully transmits the form data or encounters errors.

So, in your function call, you've supplied the `success` callback but not the `error` callback or `callback` callback. Since your function gets executed one can assume that the `ajaxSubmit` operation has successfully submitted the form.

One would be 100% correct to think that the argument gets assigned to `success` and not to `callback`.

---

Full documentation of the jQuery Forms Plugin available here: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

and here: https://github.com/malsup/form

Specifically, the documentation of the `success` callback states:

> success
>
> Callback function to be invoked after the form has been
>   submitted. If a 'success' callback function is provided it is invoked
>   after the response has been returned from the server. It is passed the
>   following arguments:
>
> 1.) responseText or responseXML value (depending on the value of the dataType option).
>
> 2.) statusText
>
> 3.) xhr (or the jQuery-wrapped form element if using jQuery < 1.4)
>
> 4.) jQuery-wrapped form element (or undefined if using jQuery < 1.4)

What this means is that the correct prototype of the success function should be:

```
triggerUpload(function(response,status,xhr,form) {
   applyPostAjax(postUrl);
});
```

Though it's perfectly fine to supply a function with more or fewer parameters because javascript allows functions to be called by fewer or more arguments than exist in their formal declaration. So if you're interested in only the result of the upload function you can just do:

```
triggerUpload(function(response) {
   applyPostAjax(postUrl);
});
```

Or if you don't care about the response from the server you can just call it like how you did.

Comment: You mean my `applyPostAjax()` is assigned to `success` instead of `callback`? And gets executed because of this `success` parameter and not `callback` parameter. So how should i use them?

Comment: To use them properly read the relevant documentation. Since `ajaxSubmit` is most likely a method of the jQuery form plugin I would start there: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#api (note: click the tabs at the top to see documentation on the options object and some example code)

Comment: I figured it out. I don't need a `callback` parameter at all. All i want is to execute `applyPostAjax(postUrl);` once the form submission is successful. So if i use the `triggerUpload` as i'm using it would be assigned to `success` and would get executed after successful form submission. I'm i correct? What about `error`? should i remove or keep it?

Comment: You may want to handle errors as well. At the very minimum just pop up a message to the user that an error occurred when submitting the data to the server and tell him to refresh or visit the page later. Like Twitter's fail whale, such error messages should not happen but when they do they make your site look a bit more professional instead of just breaking silently.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, all the three *success*, *error* and *callback* should be functions. However, they have different purpose:

- success - called once the ajax submitting is finished successfully
- error - called once there is some error in the ajax submitting
- callback - called no matter what is happening with the submitting. I guess this is added just to confirm that the *change* handler is assigned to the input field.

In other words calling triggerUpload doesn't submit the form. You just attach a handler to the file input button. Once you change it, i.e. you choose a file the form is submitted and you get a response after that.